# Serving static JavaScript file in Hapi.js not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I have created a static route like this:

```
"use strict";

var StaticPlugin = {
    register: function (server, options, next) {
        server.route([
            {
                method: 'GET',
                path: '/public/{path*}',
                config: {
                    auth: false,
                    description: 'Static assets',
                    handler: {
                        directory: {
                            path: '../public',
                            index: false,
                            listing: false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]);

        return next();
    }
};

StaticPlugin.register.attributes = {
    name: 'StaticPlugin',
    version: '1.0.0'
};

module.exports = StaticPlugin;
```

I register the plugin, but when I attempt to try to load a static JS file (going to be used to serve static js libraries), I get a 404 error.

The url I am trying to hit is `http://localhost:3000/public/javascripts/mylib.js`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your configuration the path is relative to the directory where the process is running. If this plugin is in a subdirectory and you start the server in the main directory, then the path will be incorrect. Either use a path that is relative to the project root, or use [`Path.join()`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_path1_path2) in conjunction with [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname), eg:

```
var Path = require('path');
Path.join(__dirname, '../public')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you use the plugin "Inert"